# Function that inserts a space for every Nth character in a string isn't working the way I think it should?

Tags: c++, string, insert, binary, spaces

Just to be clear, I know there are solutions for the actual code that produce the result I am looking for, but that is not what my concern is. I am concerned as to why the code that I *have already written* is not producing the desired output.

I wrote this function:

```
string ToBinary(int val, int space)
{
    string str = "";
    int tmp = int(val), num = 0;
    for (int i = INT_SIZE; i > 0; i--)
    {
        str = char((int(tmp & 1) + '0')) + str;
        tmp >>= 1;
    }
  for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); i++)
  {
    if (i % space == 0)
    {
      str.insert((i-num)," "); // num -starting at 0- is the number of spaces in the string
      num++;
    }
  }
    return str;
}
```

So this function is supposed to take an integer and convert it to a binary string, then it takes that string and iterates through each digit, while inserting a space at every interval of `space`. (in this case it's 4) So I am calling it like so, `printf("%s", ToBinary(0,4).c_str());` (0 being the first element of an array containing integers).

The first element is the number 0, so the output should be `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`, but is instead `0000 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0000000000`, and I'm not sure why?

Edit: I believe I fixed the code like so:

```
string ToBinary(int val, int space)
{
    string str = "";
    int tmp = int(val);
    for (int i = INT_SIZE; i > 0; i--)
    {
        str = char((int(tmp & 1) + '0')) + str;
        tmp >>= 1;
        if (i % space == 0)
        {
            str.insert(i-(i-1)," ");
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

I did away with the second for loop entirely, and instead decided to modify `str` within the first loop. I'm not entirely sure why this produces the desired output though as opposed to the first instance of the code posted, so if anyone knows I'd love an answer!

Comment: *So I am calling it like so, printf("%s", ToBinary(0,4));* -- Why are you using `printf`?  Use `cout`, as `printf` knows nothing about `std::string`.  The code you say you're using invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm using `printf` because I am working without iostream in this little project. Also I forgot to include `.c_str()` from main. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `num` not substract. After that change you also need to protect against inserting spaces beyond the length of the string. This code seems to work

```
for (int i = 1; i + num < str.size(); i++)
{
    if (i % space == 0)
    {
        str.insert((i+num)," "); // num -starting at 0- is the number of spaces in the string
        num++;
    }
}
```

Although it's somewhat tricksy code. I'm not sure I trust it.

Comment: Ah okay. I noticed it went out of range when adding num, but I thought that would just inherently increase the size of the string, thereby not overflowing.

Comment: So I actually fixed the problem, I believe. Refer to the original post if you're interested!

Comment: Inserting the spaces as you add the digits seems much better. But think about this code `str.insert(i-(i-1),"_");` That could be simplified!

Comment: Oh wow. I did not realize that haha. That's so funky. Thank you again! Would you happen to know why the original code (assuming it's adding num) wasn't working compared to the code now?

Comment: With `i < str.size()` and `insert(i+num, ...)` you always get a situation where i + num is >= str.size() which is the out of range issue you mentioned before. I guess you were ignoring the fact that `str.size()` increases as you insert spaces.

Comment: Oh I see so it was a conflict with the condition and the range. Thank you very much!